# How to set up IAR to use GNU make (makefile)?

Tags: makefile, iar

I have been working on Ubuntu on a project till now, but a particular mcu(TI cc2530) requires me to use IAR workbench. Eclipse can use GNU make to build projects but i cannot work with it. I need IAR for debugging a program for cc2530.
Is there anyway i can work around this?

Answer (score 1):

IAR has released plugins for Eclipse that let you use the IAR toolchain and debug without leaving the Eclipse environment. Older versions allowed editing and building within Eclipse, but required debugging via the IAR IDE. You can find the IAR Plugin Manager and all their Eclipse plugins [at their plugin repository.](http://eclipse-update.iar.com/)

With their plugin, you can either import an IAR project and convert it into an Eclipse project, or create a new Eclipse IAR toolchain project from scratch.

Comment: But this is not what @DarthSpeedious asked. He asked how to use makefiles, not eclipse. Eclipse is a very awkward way to go if you need to build in a build servers, for example...